# .NET CORE Time asynced method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have several asynec methods.

One of them triggers a `POST` method which start a process. I then need to 'sample' the results of another `GET` method every 10 minutes, and check if the status has changed from "pending" to "success" .

I tryed using`System.Threading.Timer` with no luck, complaining about my method being asynced .

> Error CS0407  'Task Campaigns.repeat(object)' has the wrong return type   Campaigns

This is my code:

```
    public async Task waitForCampaignLoadAsync(string Uri)
    {
           ...........
           var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CampaignTempleteStatus>(json);
            if(container.status == "pending")
            {
                var autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

                //The next row triggers the error
                var stateTimer = new Timer(repeat, autoEvent, 1000, (1000 * 60 * 10));
                //How can I keep repeating this, until (bool isFinished = true)??

            }

public async Task repeat(Object stateInfo)
{
    if(...)
      isFinished = true;
}
```

Another thing is , how do I pass extra info inside `repeat` function? I need to pass the `Uri` input for inner ussage ?

Comment: your code does not compile

Comment: @MelGerats That makes sense regarding what I've stated.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Yossi you don't need `AutoResetEvent` with tasks and async/await. If you want to cancel the timer, use a CancellationToken.

Comment: @Yossi what are you trying to do? Poll something? Why not use `Task.Delay()` in a loop then, or use an API that *doesn't* need polling? You could use a TaskCompletionSource to convert other asynchronous patterns like callbacks, events, to a Task

Comment: @Yossie you could also use HttpClient whose methods are already asynchronous to call HTTP APIs without blocking, combined with a CancellationToken to stop polling when needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an asynchronous method starts getting complicated it's a sure sign something is wrong. Most of the time async code looks almost the same as synchronous code with the addition of `await`.

A simple polling loop could be as simple as :

```
public async Task<string> waitForCampaignLoadAsync(string uri)
{
    var client=new HttpClient();
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        var json = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
        var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CampaignTempleteStatus>(json);
        if (container.status != "pending")
        {
            return container.status;
        }
        await Task.Delay(10000); 
    }
    return "Timed out!";
}
```

[Cancellation in managed threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) explains how CancellationTokenSource and CancellationToken can be used to cancel threads, tasks and asynchronous functions. Many asynchronous methods already provide overloads that accept a CancellationToken parameter. The polling function could be modified to accept and check a canellation token :

```
public async Task<string> waitForCampaignLoadAsync(string uri,CancellationToken token=default)
{
    var client=new HttpClient();
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        var json = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
        var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CampaignTempleteStatus>(json);
        if (container.status != "pending")
        {
            return container.status;
        }
        await Task.Delay(10000,token); 
    }
    return "Timed out!";
}
```

A CancellationTokenSource can be used to call this method with an overall timeout of eg, 5 minutes :

```
 var cts=new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
 try
 {
     var result=waitForCampaignLoadAsync(uri,cts.Token);
     //Process the result ....
 }
 catch(OperationCancelledExcepction ex)
 {
     //Handle the timeout here
 }
```

This code can be improved. For example, `GetStringAsync()` doesn't accept a cancellation token. The operation can be broken in two steps though, one call to `GetAsync()` with a cancellation token that waits for the server to send a result 
and another to `HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync()` to read the response, eg :

```
var response=await client.GetAsync(uri,token)
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var json=await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of Timer is a TimerCallback delegate, which should return void

```
var stateTimer = new Timer(Repeat, autoEvent, 1000, (1000 * 60 * 10));

private void Repeat(object state)
{
    ....
}
```